# The origin of "The Lost Boarding Pass Problem"

Tags: probability-theory, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, puzzle, math-history

There are several post here concerning "The Lost Boarding Pass Problem":

[The Lost Boarding Pass Advanced](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255806/the-lost-boarding-pass-advanced)

[Advanced airplane problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574580/advanced-airplane-problem)

[Taking Seats on a Plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5595/taking-seats-on-a-plane)

[Generalize airplane problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493175/generalize-airplane-problem)

But what is the origin of this problem?

It is definitely older than Winkler's "Mathematical puzzles: a connoisseur's collection". In Russia it was known many years before as "the crazy old lady problem" or "the drunk Tyson problem".

The article [The lost boarding pass, and other practical problems](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Egrg/papers/lost-bp3.pdf) gives some references but they are far from the origin as well.

Answer (score 1):

It appeared as Problem 735 in the September 2002 issue of *The College Mathematics Journal*.  The solution in the September 2003 issue referenced the December 2001 issue of *FAMOS*.

Comment: In Russia it was a folklor problem before this publication. At least it was published in 1997.